# How to target a specific key in a JSON object then match by id in that key's array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm kinda new to JS and having trouble simulating array methods on objects. I'm getting this response back from a fetch and I would like to just grab the 'entries' key then use the native Array.find() on 'entries' to match an id with the matchThisId variable. I tried using a for..in loop but I don't know how to access 'entries' from there like then loop through that. TypeScript yells that I can't access by string.

```
const matchThisId = 2;

const fetchResponse = {
  author: 'Mike',
  description: 'description'
  entries: [
    {id: 1, url: 'url1'},
    {id: 2, url: 'url2'},
    {id: 3, url: 'url3'}
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
for (let key in fetchResponse) {
   return key['entries'].find(id => id === matchThisId);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but rather than iterate through each `fetchResponse` object to find `entries`, just access that property directly. Your `find` function will return an element from the array, which in your case is an object, and you then compare the object property to the target value.

```js
let matchThisId = 2
const fetchResponse = {
  author: 'Mike',
  description: 'description',
  entries: [
    {id: 1, url: 'url1'},
    {id: 2, url: 'url2'},
    {id: 3, url: 'url3'}
  ]
}
console.log(fetchResponse.entries.find(el => el.id === matchThisId))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
const fetchResponse = {
      author: 'Mike',
      description: 'description',
      entries: [
        {id: 1, url: 'url1'},
        {id: 2, url: 'url2'},
        {id: 3, url: 'url3'}
      ]
    };
    const findData = fetchResponse.entries.find((row) => row.id === 1);
    console.log('findData', findData) // { id: 1, url: 'url1' }
```

now if you want more dynamically

```
const findDateDynamically = Object.entries(fetchResponse).reduce((lastValue, [name, value]) => {
      if (name === 'entries' && Array.isArray(value) ) {
        return value?.find((row) => row.id === 2);
      }
    }, {});
    console.log('findDateDynamically', findDateDynamically) // { id: 2, url: 'url2' }
```